# How to create a loop before downloading a file checking your current file?

Tags: bash, loops, if-statement

This is how I started.  Something easy.

```
a="abc"
b="ABC"

if [ "$a" == "$b" ]; then
    echo "Strings $a & $b match"
else
    echo "Strings $a don't match $b"
fi
```

Then I tried this. In which it always states skipping even if I haven't yet downloaded it.

```
input="file"
while IFS= read -r line; do
path="${line%/*}"
file="${line##*/}"

if [ $line = $file ]; then
     echo "skipping ${file##*/}"
else
     wget -nc -q --show-progress "${path}/${file}"
  sleep 1
fi
done < "$input"
```

I also tried this.  I know this is wrong because I have nothing for y to match x.  I was trying to use y as a variable in wget to match something in my file x.

```
for x in $(cat file); do
for y in ???; do

if [ "$x" == "$y" ]; then
     echo "${x##*/} & ${y##*/} match skipping download"
else
     echo "${x##*/} don't match ${y##*/} downloading"
  sleep 1
     wget -q -nc --show-progress "$y"
fi
done
done
```

I really just want to run a basic loop being able to check my file as I'm downloading.  Skip file if already there and if not download file.

Comment: Why not just `wget -N` ?

Comment: I'm pretty new to this and looking for any possibilities. Hoping to add a little more to my bash if this works and getting experience learning to code. Thanks.

Comment: What is in the `"$input"` file? Please post sample input. What is going on in your script? What do you want to achieve? And why not just use `wget -N` ? The `[ $line = $file ]` just compares strings, it doesn't check if a file exists.  What is that you want to do with your scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need a second loop

Just check if file is readable and download if isn't.

```
#!/bin/bash

CHECKFILE="$1"

while read line; do

    if [ ! -r $line ]; then
        echo "File: $line not found"
        #change touch line to your wget
        #wget ....
        touch $line
    else
        echo "Found: $line"
    fi

done < "$CHECKFILE"
```

Remember linux is case sensitive. 
Of course, you can have multiple data in your line and split it to get the filename and path.

The result of the script will be.

```
$>ls -1
a.txt
b.txt
d.txt
files.txt
test.sh
$>cat files.txt
a.txt
b.txt
c.txt
d.txt
e.txt
A.txt
a.txt
$>test.sh files.txt
Found: a.txt
Found: b.txt
File: c.txt not found
Found: d.txt
File: e.txt not found
File: A.txt not found
Found: a.txt
$>ls -1tr
d.txt
b.txt
a.txt
files.txt
test.sh
c.txt
e.txt
A.txt
$>
```